# oledbdataadapter failing to read a specific cell in specific condition from csv

Tags: c#, csv, oledbdataadapter

I have a csv file with the following data:

**FIBO.csv**

```
41,3
36445122,EURUSD,4,0.01,1.05828,1,1.00881,10,66
36445121,EURUSD,4,0.01,1.05828,1,1.00881,10,66
36445120,EURUSD,4,0.01,1.05828,1,1.00881,10,66
```

When I read this file using `OLEDB` provider, it correctly returns the perfect datatable.

That code is here:

```
public DataTable CsvFileToDatatable(string path, bool IsFirstRowHeader)
{
    string header = "No";
    string sql = string.Empty;
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    string pathOnly = string.Empty;
    string fileName = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        pathOnly = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path);
        sql = @"SELECT * FROM [" + fileName + "]";
        if (IsFirstRowHeader)
        {
            header = "Yes";
        }
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathOnly +
            ";Extended Properties=\"Text;IMEX = 1;HDR=" + header + "\""))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    dataTable = new DataTable();
                    dataTable.Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
                    adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        if (dataTable == null)
            dataTable = new DataTable();
    }
    finally
    {
    }
    return dataTable;
}
```

BUT when csv file has values like this:

```
41,3
36445122,EURUSD,4,0.01,1.05828,1,1.00881,10,66
```

then the returned datatable has **EURUSD** missing.

If I add another row, all data returns perfectly.  The problem happens only if I have two rows, like just above.

I had several files like this and they all have the same problem(s).  I am not sure what is wrong with this.

I have set `IMEX=1`, but nothing works.

Comment: What is the value of your variable "header" ?

Comment: No. i have used `TypeGuessRows=0`. but that made my first two column header disapear and instead, it shows `41,1`... which were my first row. and in the first row, the full data row is showing with "EURUSD"

Comment: If you wrap each value in the CSV file by a quote ", it will work. But do you have control on the input data ?
"41","3"
"36445122","EURUSD","4","0.01","1.05828","1","1.00881","10","66"

Comment: No, I dont have the control. I cannot do this.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/2254e3af-2fa1-4003-a843-394a6bf94661/bug-microsoftjetoledb40-does-not-read-in-string-values-on-number-columns-from-csv?forum=exceldev), it seems to be a bug from JET.OLEDB.4.

Instead of using OleDbConnection, check this third party library [KBCsv](http://kbcsv.codeplex.com/). I have tried it as below and it worked:

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(ope.FileName, FileMode.Open);
using (CsvReader reader = new CsvReader(stream))
{
    while (reader.HasMoreRecords)
    {
        DataRecord record = reader.ReadDataRecord();
        string row0 = record[0];
        string row1 = record[1];
        Console.WriteLine($"{row0}, {row1}");
    }
}
```

Below is the output after running my code above :

```
41,3
36445122,EURUSD
```

Comment: thanks for your rapid answer. how does `TypeGuessRows` work?